# How to pick Activity to start from the launcher based on SDK version?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an Android application which has multiple entry points in the launcher.
Some of these requires a higher SDK version than others, and I want to disable or hide these if the device has a lower SDK version than what they require.

Basically my Manifest looks like this:

```
<application
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        ...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ... // more launcher activities follows
</application>
```

`Activity1` requires SDK version 19, but `Activity2` requires SDK version 21. My minimum SDK version is 19.
I want `Activity2` hidden to be when installing the application on devices with SDK version < 21.

I know I can do a check in the `onCreate` method of `Activity2` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

But the activity will obviously still show up in the launcher.

I'm also aware that this is a rather unique problem, and for most people with the same issue, the simplest and probably best solution is to just not have multiple activities as launcher activities, but this will not work so well in my use case.

Comment: You can use Spalsh Screen before your Main activity and check Sdk version there

Comment: I also think splash screen is an answer. Another way to achieve this is using flavors to have separate api levels. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html#minsdkversion https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Comment: @KapilParmar @Toris using and aditional activity for this (a splash screen) is totally unnecessary and adds overhead, this can be done using `android:enabled` in combination with API level specific booleans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please don't do this in code, the only correct way to do this is to use the `android:enabled="true/false"` property which can be set on components in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file like an `Activity` or `BroadcastReceiver`. Instead of hard-coding the boolean value, use a boolean resource that changes per API level:

**values/bools.xml:** Both activities are disabled by default

```
<bool name="activity_1_enabled">false</bool>
<bool name="activity_2_enabled">false</bool>
```

**values-v19/bools.xml:** On SDK 19 up to 20 activity 1 is enabled and 2 disabled

```
<bool name="activity_1_enabled">true</bool>
<bool name="activity_2_enabled">false</bool>
```

**values-v21/bools.xml:** On SDK 21+ both the activities are enabled

```
<bool name="activity_1_enabled">true</bool>
<bool name="activity_2_enabled">true</bool>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity1"
    android:enabled="@bool/activity_1_enabled" />

<activity
    android:name=".Activity2"
    android:enabled="@bool/activity_2_enabled" />
```

Comment: values (1:true, 2:false) and values-v21 (1:false, 2:true) are enough for values, and (1:true, 2:true) will not work, I think.

Comment: If the device is SDK version 22 both activities will be enabled (it will use the values-v21 folder).

Comment: I just tried it out and it works perfectly - thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, and they will both show up in the launcher (as intended) - if they are not enabled=false :)

Comment: @Toris you can have two activities with main and launcher but you do need to specify the preferred one using: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>`

Comment: I see. But what will happen if user has selected Activity1 on devices with API21?

Comment: Actually you don't even have to specify that. At least I'm not :) But if you don't you will need to modify your Run/Debug Configuration so that it starts a specific Activity and not the default.